# how to keep softkeyboard even after I clicked send button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-softkeyboard

I use EditText to do input actions, and set `android:imeOptions="actionSend"` to the widget, so that the soft keyboard can have a send button, but when I click send, the soft keyboard will disappeared, however, it's not friendly to users since user must click EditText again to use the soft keyboard, all I want is to keep the soft keyboard, does any one know how to achieve it?
Here is a piece of my layout code：

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_area"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/emo_btn"
        android:inputType="textAutoCorrect"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"/>
```

Comment: you are using `setOnEditorActionListener` or `setOnKeyListener` ? on both case try your return statement with `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using `setOnEditorActionListener` or `setOnKeyListener` ? on both case try your return statement with `true`